# All winforms resource files into a single resource file

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I have been trying to localize a WinForms application for a while. I have used the method that I set the form's Localizable property true, changed the Language and changed the control's Text properties.The problem is my app has multiple forms and I don't want to have a resource file for each form, I would like to localize the app with a common,single resource file. Should I merge these resource files or is there an other way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think, you should use a single resx file for all the winforms, and a wrapper class that interact with resx and winforms.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. And unclear how designer should localize forms (if they are not per-language, then where should it keep different values, to example, for `Label`s) .   But you are always free to implement own localization manager, which will not work with designer . Why multiple resx-files per form are problem? Is your actual problem related to presense of satellite assemblies (multiple folders and dlls inside near exe-file)?

Comment: Actually, I have a resource file per-language and per form.I want to localize the forms by a single/global resource file, problem is not with the dlls.@Rohit, I follow  a way like you mentioned, but I wonder if there is another way.